# How can a friend and I play two complementary characters effectively as a duo?

Tags: dnd-4e, character-creation

In 2 weeks I'll be participating in a new campaign at level 1. A friend and I want to play Eladrin twins as mobile, preferably stealthy, characters with complementary skills and abilities, and be relatively similar in flavour.

We like the idea of back-to-back fighting and great tactical teamwork.

The trouble I'm having is getting through all the material (pretty much every sourcebook available) and finding good combos.

We have no idea what other characters will be in the group.

Any ideas would be welcome.

**Essentially, what feats and skills are good to take to make a powerful team out of two Eladrin?**

Comment: You're going to get need a lot more detail to get a good answer here, but I will give you one thing, Iliyanbruen Guardian, is an excellent theme for a pair of eladrin to take. The first level feature allows you to take an ally when you fey step. After that, party composition should dictate a lot. Eladrin have some cool class features, and you guys could quite nicely fill in the leader and striker roles with a dex based strike (rogue, scout, thief, etc) and a cha or int based leader (highly recommend skald here).

Answer (score 4):

**One of the most effective "buddy teams" is a Striker and a Leader. Specifically, a striker that gets her striker damage every *turn* instead of round on a melee basic attack, and a leader that grants melee basic attacks.**

From there, we can look at your requirements: Eladrin twins at level 1, with high mobility and stealth.

Twin 1, therefore, is a Thief. The thief "build" has been mostly solved, and I would borrow heavily from builds featured [here](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/27050849/What_Is_Yours_Can_Be_Mine:_A_Thiefs_Handbook&post_num=10#486645241). Alternatively, an eladrin can make an excellent cunning-sneak rogue, if you want a little more complexity in your build.

Twin 2, must be one of the trifecta: Warlord, Ardent, Shaman. Warlords, unless they're lazy (and boring) really would like strength, but you could play an exellent Insightful Warlord. If you go this route, make sure to allow the warlord to roll her granted attacks. Otherwise there will be very very little rolling for her. Ardent is also an option, and my favourite class. Unfortunately, the ardent is slightly suboptimal due to the wording on "Ire Strike" which requires an adjacent ally, and therefore is more difficult to present the ardent as a flanking buddy versus "Commander's Strike" which does just that. On the other hand, it's more fun for "back to back" fighting. Shaman is good, but out of the running due to your requirements for melee shenanigans.

With more details, we'd be happy to make specific builds for the twins in chat.